# How to enable geolocation on Chrome when running a project with create-react-app (npm start)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome

I started a project with create-react-app and I live preview it in localhost by running 'npm start'. Since it is not http served, Chrome won't allow the geolocation to work.

How do people usually go about solving this problem and testing geolocation related features?

Comment: I just installed a fresh version of create-react-app. I used the npm library react-geolocated and ran the app without making any configurations aside from creating a component that uses the npm library I just mentioned. When I run the app the browser asked me to approve the app's ability to access my location. Once I accepted it shows my lat and long in the browser as the component should. If you are having some problem outside of what I just described can you please elaborate and show us some code as well as the error? Otherwise I am happy to answer the question to show you what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right way of doing this is to start the application with `https=true npm start` according to the create-react-app docs.

Answer (score 0):

**Background -**

**My second (2) answer will absolutely let you access your app over https.**

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish or what is blocking you, but I think I can give you what you need in one of two answers.

**Solutions -**

**Answer 1.** If you simply want to have the browser show your location it will work on a fresh install of `create-react-app`.

```
npm i -g create-react-app
create-react-app geo
cd geo
npm i 
npm i --save react-geolocation 
npm start
```

Create a file names `Geolocation.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { geolocated } from "react-geolocated";

class Demo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return !this.props.isGeolocationAvailable ? (
            <div>Your browser does not support Geolocation</div>
        ) : !this.props.isGeolocationEnabled ? (
            <div>Geolocation is not enabled</div>
        ) : this.props.coords ? (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>latitude</td>
                        <td>{this.props.coords.latitude}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>longitude</td>
                        <td>{this.props.coords.longitude}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>altitude</td>
                        <td>{this.props.coords.altitude}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>heading</td>
                        <td>{this.props.coords.heading}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>speed</td>
                        <td>{this.props.coords.speed}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        ) : (
            <div>Getting the location data&hellip; </div>
        );
    }
}

export default geolocated({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
    },
    userDecisionTimeout: 5000,
})(Demo);
```

In App.js add the new component

```
import Geolocated from './Geolocated';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">   
      <Geolocated />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Answer 2.** You can create an https URL for your local application in development using npm libraries like `ngrok`.

Make sure your **react app is running on port 3000** if you follow this example. The port passed to ngrok is the port that ngrok will create the secure tunnel to.

```
npm i -g ngrok
ngrok 3000
```

> ngrok by @inconshreveable
>   (Ctrl+C to quit)
>                                                                                                                         Session Status                online
>   Session Expires               7 hours, 59 minutes
>   Version                       2.3.35
>   Region                        United States (us)
>   Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
>   Forwarding                    http://33333.ngrok.io ->
>   http://localhost:3000                                       Forwarding
>   https://33333.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                   Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50
> ```
>
> p90
>                                 6       1       0.09    0.02    2.90    5.00
>                                                                                                                         HTTP Requests
>
> ---
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                   GET /favicon.ico                    200 OK
> ```
>
> GET /sockjs-node                    101 Switching Protocols
>   GET /static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg 200 OK
>   GET /static/js/main.chunk.js        200 OK
>   GET /static/js/0.chunk.js           200 OK
>   GET /static/js/bundle.js            200 OK
>   GET /                               200 OK

In the output you should see an https URL that is forwarding to your localhost port 3000 application as long as you keep it running.

Here is a screenshot of the geolocation working...

[image]